# jQuery one() limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a set of events the first time a specific element is clicked. Also, another set of events the first time another element is clicked.

Currently, just the first function is working. Nothing happens when I click the next element. No console errors, nothing.

```
$("#make-rect").one("click", function() {
    $('.js-tour-1').addClass('hidden');
    $('.js-tour-2').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(".elemRect").one("dblclick", function() {
  $('.js-tour-2').addClass('hidden');
  $('.js-tour-3').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine when applied to buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/7Bhb2/ Maybe show your html.

Comment: Did you remember to double-click the second element?

Comment: Ah wait, I think I know the problem. The second trigger gets drawn with JS when I click the first trigger. So I think that's the problem. Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how you solved this issue? People running into similar problems and reading this question would want to know.

Comment: It turns out, there was no issue with the code above, it works fine. In my app though, I'm building elements with Javascript, so existing functions don't get called on new elements, I need to call the function each time I build a new element.